# How to read complicated spring configuration from map?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, configuration

I have the following property `application.properties` file:

```
mapper.url1=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_111\\bin\\java.exe
mapper.url2=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_111\\bin\\javaw.exe
```

and following bean, which reflection in java code:

```
@Component
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties
public class ApplicationProperties {
    private Map<String, String> mapper;
    //get and set methods
    ....
```

Now I want to extend this format and add  timeout to the key.

I expect that the most readable(I do not insist, you can suggest another) format would be:

```
mapper.url1=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_111\\bin\\java.exe
mapper.url1.timeOut=1000
```

How to extend my configuration to read this(or another with same power) format?

Where does correct place to validate it?
I want to validate property file format. Each key should contain both: path and timeout. Otherwise application should not be started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a nested class to represent the properties.

For example:

```java
@ConfigurationProperties
public class DemoApplication {

    ...

    public static class UrlProperties {
        // use Path or File so it's type-safe
        private Path path;

        // use int for type-safety 
        private int timeout;

        public Path getPath() {
            return path;
        }

        public void setPath(final Path path) {
            this.path = path;
        }

        public int getTimeout() {
            return timeout;
        }

        public void setTimeout(final int timeout) {
            this.timeout = timeout;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "UrlProperties{" + "path=" + path + ", timeout=" + timeout + '}';
        }
    }
}
```

and then define your `Map` instance variable with a `String` key and a value as the nested class type:

`private Map<String, UrlProperties> mapper;`

and use the properties like this:

```
mapper.url1.path=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_111\\bin\\java.exe
mapper.url1.timeout=1000

mapper.url2.path=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_111\\bin\\javaw.exe
mapper.url2.timeout=5000
```

You'll end up with objects that look like this:

```
{url2=UrlProperties{path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin\javaw.exe, timeout=5000}, url1=UrlProperties{path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin\java.exe, timeout=1000}}
```

Additionally, with Spring Boot 1.5, you can use JSR-303 annotations to validate your `ConfigurationProperties`. See [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.5-Release-Notes#configurationproperties-validation) for more details.

Comment: you define map as field in your example(not inner class)

Comment: Right, mapper is an instance variable of type Map with the key being a string and the value the nested class.

Comment: Made some additional edits. Hopefully that is more clear.